# uitableview reload not working on arm64 devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have an UITableView that does not reload data on arm64 devices. The tableview loads data when the app is first launched but subsequent reloads don't load data. 
The same app version works on armv7s devices. The interesting thing is when I attach a arm64 device to XCode to debug, the table view reloads the data. If I delete the app and run the app again without XCode, the tableview does not reload.

I am able to verify through logs that the following delegate methods for tableview are called after `[self.tableView reloadData]`. However the table does not update in the UI.

```
 - numberOfSectionsInTableView 
 - numberOfRowsInSection  
 - scrollViewDidScroll 
 - cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

This is what I have narrowed it down to.If I compile with arm64 support in Build Settings, the table view does not refresh on arm64 devices. If I remove arm64 from build settings, the tableview does refresh, however I can't upload to App Store because it is not 64 bit enabled.

Has anyone else seen this type of behavior or could point me to anything that could be causing this?

Here's the code black where I'm calling the tableview reload

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // The request is complete and data has been received
    // You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
    NSError* error;
    NSMutableArray *newFeeds;

    newFeeds = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
#if DEBUG
    //[Flurry logEvent:newFeeds.description];


#endif
    NSLog(@"newFeeds count %lu", (unsigned long)newFeeds.count);
    if([self.requestType isEqual:@"top"])
    {
        //feeds = [feeds arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newFeeds];
        NSLog(@"requestType isEqual:@top");
        NSComparator compareDates = ^(NSDictionary *feed1, NSDictionary *feed2){
            NSDate *date1 =[feed1 objectForKey:@"d"];
            NSDate *date2 =[feed2 objectForKey:@"d"];
            if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending){
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending){
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            }
            else{
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }
        };
        for (NSDictionary *feed in newFeeds)
        {
            //int i = -1;
            int j = -1;
            //NSDate *feedDate = [feed objectForKey:@"d"];
            NSUInteger newIndex = [self.feeds indexOfObject:feed inSortedRange:(NSRange){0, [self.feeds count]} options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:compareDates];
            //i = [self.feeds indexOfObject:feed inRange:(NSMakeRange)(newIndex,(self.feeds.count-newIndex))];
            j = [self.feeds indexOfObject:feed];
            if(j == NSNotFound)
            {
                [self.feeds insertObject:feed atIndex:newIndex];
            }
        }
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"requestType isNotEqual:@top");
        self.feeds = newFeeds;


    }
    [self archiveFeeds:self.feeds];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Can you explain, this method don't call, or your `UITableView` don't update its cells?

Comment: The UITableView does not update the cells.

Comment: Try: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData]; }`

Comment: @shallowThought Ignore my (now deleted) previous comment. Adding the async does not make a difference. This is what I have narrowed it down to.     If I compile with arm64 support in Build Settings, the table view does not refresh on arm64 devices. If I remove arm64 from build settings, the tableview does refresh, however I can't upload to App Store because it is not 64 bit enabled.

Comment: Which exact setting do you refer to? "Valid Architectures"? Also, to pinpoint the root of the issue, try out different "Optimisation Level" settings.